# spring data jpa save manually assign identifier

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i use spring save

```
  HighWay highWay = new HighWay();
     highWay.setId("000");
    HighWayRepository hRepository = (HighWayRepository) context
                    .getBean("highWayRepository");
            hRepository.save(highWay);
            hRepository.flush();


    public interface HighWayRepository extends JpaRepository<HighWay, String> {

    }
```

the table is like  `f_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,

```
public class HighWay {
    @Id
    @Column(name="f_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;}
```

but throws exception

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'f_id' doesn't have a default
>   value     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1169)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:693)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1404)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1318)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1303)
>     at
>   com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DruidPooledPreparedStatement.java:253)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     ... 51 more

i check the document, 
Id-Property inspection (default)    By default Spring Data JPA inspects the Id-Property of the given Entity. If the Id-Property is null, then the entity will be assumed as new, otherwise as not new.

the sql is like Hibernate: `insert into us_highway (blockTime, blockType, endNum, predictTime, publishTime, roadName, situation, startNum, tips) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`
not id is insert!

because i want to assign id manually,the id-property is not null if new ,how to configure to save ?

Comment: If you assign the identifier yourself don't use a `@GeneratedValue` as that basically lets the database control the ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are assigning Id manually.Remove below annotation on id.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```